# Javascript: Word reverse function undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, reverse

I am trying to create a word reverser function that will reverse the letter order of each word in a string,  without using any loops.

So far I have this:

```
var strFlip = function(str){
  splitStr = str.split(" ");{
    return;
  }
  var wordFlip = function reverse(splitStr){
    return splitStr.split('').reverse().join('');
  };  
};

console.log(strFlip("Hello Hannah"));
```

The wordFlip part correctly reverses the order of a single word if used independent of the rest of the code. However, the overall code continually outputs `undefined`. I am unfamiliar with Javascript, so I assume I am simply not noticing a simple structural issue.

Comment: I now understand my biggest issue. I thought that my code was returning nested function's results to be used throughout the master function in following nested expressions. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this part causes the function to return immediately, and since it is returning nothing, you get `undefined`:

```
var strFlip = function(str){
  splitStr = str.split(" ");{
    return; //<-- immediately returns here
  }
  ...

};
```

I'm not sure what that part is trying to do, but to actually do what you want, you can do this:

```
var strFlip = function(str) {
    //Since you are using a variable as a reference to a function
    //expression/literal, there is no hoisting so you have to
    //predefine
    var wordFlip = function reverse(splitStr) {
        return splitStr.split('').reverse().join('');
    };

    return str.split(" ").map(wordFlip).join(" ");    
}
```

A more elegant approach would be to forgo `wordFlip` and just use an anonymous callback to `map`:

```
var strFlip = function(str) {
    return str.split(" ").map(function(word) {
        return word.split("").reverse().join("");
    }).join(" ");    
}
```

To understand what `map` does, let's look at `forEach` first since `map` works in a similar manner. When you use `array.forEach(callback)`, the function `callback` is called for every element in `array`. It is equivalent to the following code:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    callback(array[i]);
}
```

Essentially it is a "functional" way of iterating over an array and doing something with each element. `map` also does this; it iterates over the array as well, but *converts* (maps) each element of the array to *something else* and returns a *new* array consisting of the mapped elements. The *something else* is defined by the behavior of `callback`. Here's an example that is similar to the example above. Here I'm specifying an actual `callback` as well so that you can see the behavior a little better:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
var squares = [];

function square(num) {
    return num * num;
}

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    squares[i] = square(array[i]);
}
```

Here, `square` is the same as `callback` and it is called for each element. The return value of `square` is then used to construct the new array. Using `map`, you can rewrite the above as:

```
var squares = array.map(function(num) {
    return num * num;
});
```

Now applying this to the solution, you can see that we are mapping *each word* in the sentence *to its reverse* and then joining on the mapped array.

Comment: Your recommended solution is perfect, however I am confused by what `.map()` is doing exactly?

Comment: @CharlesWatson I'll update my answer to explain more fully.

Comment: Your further explanation has helped immensely, thank you!

Comment: @CharlesWatson glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

You're overcomplicating things by trying to nest a function inside a function. Create a single function that does both the work of reversing the words and characters:

```js
var flipper = function reverse(splitStr) {
  return splitStr.split('').reverse().join('').split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
};


alert(flipper("Hello Hannah"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty close, but the code is a little overbusy.  Try this:

```
function reverse(splitStr) {
    return splitStr.split('').reverse().join('');
}

console.log(reverse('Hello Hannah'));
```

I just took the main workhorse out of your code and simplified the function.  You were on the right track,

**EDIT**

If you want to keep the words in place, like Vivin suggested, you can do something like:

```
function reverse(splitStr) {
    var strs = splitStr.split(' ');

    var reverseInPlace = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
        reverseInPlace.push(strs[i].split('').reverse().join(''));
    }

    return reverseInPlace.join(' ');
}

console.log(reverse('Hello Hannah'));
```

Comment: This returns `"hannaH olleH"` instead of `"olleH hannaH"`. I suspect the OP wants the latter.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be `split` the sentence by empty spaces and then `reverse` and `join` empty spaces `split` again by a space then `reverse` and `join` with an empty space.

If you do that then:

`"Hello Hannah"` will be transformed to `"olleH hannaH"`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** You can define the prototype to string as your own extension for one line solution.

```js
String.prototype.Flip = function() {
    return this.split("").reverse().join("").split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
};

var a="Hello Hannah";
alert(a.Flip());
```